# sklearn Pipeline with NaN values

Tags: scikit-learn

For good reasons, most ( all ? ) of the sklearn methods that implement `fit` and `transform` ( transformers or estimators ) don't play nice with data that contains NaN values. Because most machine learning algorithms can't handle these out of the box, and various transforms are ambiguous with NaN ( what's an interaction between a feature with a 6 and one with NaN ? ), an error is raised when you're trying to pass a dataset containing null values into, say, `StandardScaler`, `PCA`, and `RandomForestClassifier`.

However, I'm currently using an estimator that is able to deal with missing values. This is fairly important for my dataset because most pieces of data will have at least one missing feature ( so dropping NAs is out of the question ), and imputing is more or less impossible ( many of the columns in the original data are strings like addresses or names ). My features are numerical, but there's no good way to encode a missing value in a feature that's the fuzzy distance between strings.

In my dataset, NAs arise when I'm comparing two strings but one or both are missing. Encoding these NAs as zero is telling the model that the strings are very dissimilar, which isn't the same as saying "we don't know", and could lead to wrongful classification.

For context, my classifier is currently an XGBoost boosted forest classifier, and these take missing data without issue. This classifier "learns" the best imputation value by learning the correct direction to take on any split where the data is missing.

**TL; DR** : is there a good way to use sklearn's various transformer objects whilst keeping missing data ? Examples of reasonable behaviour for me would be :

- `StandardScaler` uses `np.nanmean` and similar methods to ignore NaN when scaling the data
- `PolynomialFeatures` does the standard feature generation, but anywhere there's a NaN, the result is a NaN. That is, the interaction between features "A" and "B", when "A" is 6 and "B" is NaN, is simply NaN. B^2 is NaN.
- `PCA` is a more difficult question, which I'll leave out for now...

My current thought is to write my own versions of these objects with the correct logic, writing whatever attributes Pipeline needs them to have to work correctly in the Pipeline object. There's no documentation that I can find on this, so I've written something with `fit`, `transform`, `fit_transform`, and `get_params`, but I'm getting some mysterious errors that I haven't puzzled out yet.

Any help appreciated. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: it's a good question, i think you're probably going to have to roll your own though.

Comment: I think so, @maxymoo . I'm going through http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects right now.

Comment: if you work it you should contribute it back ;)

Comment: Note that StandardScaler now accepts NaN values. Quoting the documentation for [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html): "NaNs are treated as missing values: disregarded in fit, and maintained in transform." . sklearn version: 0.23.2